# Bootstrap layout issue - row divs floating out of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m experiencing two issues with a bootstrap layout on a website that I’m building and I’m wondering if someone can point out where I’m going wrong. I have put my site live on a sub domain so that you can see the issue I am facing. It can be found here http://cefn.mywebsitebuild.co.uk//fixtures-results/first-team/

Issue one
The col-xs-12 fix-result div is floating outside the container and im unsure why. I also want this to align with the image see green line on my image

[image]

Issue two
The col-xs-12 match-sponsor div is also floating outside the container and I’m unsure why

[image]
I have uploaded my page source http://www.bootlint.com/ and its tells me that there are problems with your code.

Can someone please tell me what I can do to get this working?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to adjust div's for that one image. I would strongly recommend to leave current bootstrap settings. Instead if you want to fill div with that image, add this attribute to parent div of that image.This way image would be aligned with rest of your divs.

```
style="
    padding: 0px 0px;
"
```

Comment: The reason I want to adjust the divs (with the blue border) is because it doesn't look to good on a mobile. I would like margins on a mobile. Is my bootstrap nested ok? I'm still learning this. Thanks

Comment: How would you suggest fixing issue 2?

Comment: @Paul, your bootstrap nesting is fine i.e row->col->row->col->elements, You don't want to have something like row->col->row->elements. 
Issue two can fixed by overriding style of parent .row div by adding following styles, 

`margin-right: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;`

Comment: i fixed this issue by applying the following to the parent row div <div class="row" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;">. I will create a class apply the style in css and then add the class rather than using inline style. thansk for your help

Comment: @Paul, Glad it worked out for you. Please Upvote if I was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You nest your rows differently. This is the *easiest* fix:

```
<!-- This is your very first row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row"> <!-- INSERT ROW HERE -->
            <h4 class="heading-mini">First Team Fixtures &amp; Results</h4>
            <img src="/media/1014/img_5507.jpg?crop=0,0.24305557250976545,0.0000000000000007579122514774,0.33194442749023489&amp;cropmode=percentage&amp;rnd=131162832050000000" class="img-responsive team-photo" alt="" title="">
                <p class="photo-names">Back row (left to right): Paul Griffiths, Nathan Williams, Sam Roberts, Oliver Davies, Jamie Rawlinson</p>
        </div> <!-- END ROW HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I wouldn't go so far to say that it's the *best* fix... sorry. (I would opt for removing a nested row/columns everywhere else... )

Issue 2 is the same thing. (Everywhere else you have nested row->col->row->col.)

Comment: Thanks, originally my rows and columns were so nested but in trying to fix this issue I have ended up with this markup. The bootstrap validator tells me that is all valid markup?

Answer (score 0):

Hi fixed this by adding the following to the parent row divs

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;">
```

The nested bootstrap validates and It now looks as i wanted (hope its correct)

[image]

I plan to create a class apply the margin fix and apply the class tto the parent row divs instead of using inline style.

Thanks